# Excel formula separate text to date

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have an excel format, for example
How to separate data below with formula and becoming date like example below?

```
AGH20180301 ==> 01/03/2018
PRM20170301 ==> 01/03/2017
EXE20120407 ==> 07/04/2012
```

Answer (score 2):

Based on your specific examples, this will work:

```
=DATE(MID(A1,4,4),MID(A1,8,2),MID(A1,10,2))
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this formula and format it any way you want.

```
=--REPLACE(REPLACE(MID(A1,4,8),7,0,"-"),5,0,"-")
```

[image]